# Why should \hline be the first instruction in a tabular row?

Tags: tables, hline

While debugging a macro, I've spotted this weird behavior (by weird, I mean I don't have the skill to understand why it is that way, and if it's a bug or a feature...).

This MWE compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn\mytable:n {
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \hline
    test \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\mytable}{\mytable:n}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \mytable
\end{document}
```

But this one won't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn\mytable:n {
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \bool_set_true:N\myvar % <--- Here the change
    \hline
    test \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\mytable}{\mytable:n}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \mytable
\end{document}
```

My intuition tells me that except for defining some other macro or store some tokens in register, the `\bool_set_true:N` function would not do anything meaningful to the input/output, but I guess this proves me wrong... Can somebody provide me a better intuition on this one?

(**NOTE** : After reading the comments, anything put before the `\hline` (`\def` etc.) raises the problem)

Comment: It doesn't work because `\hline` has to be the very first(ish) thing in a table cell.  `\bool_set_true:N` gets in the way and breaks `\hline`.

Comment: This is not directly related to `expl3`, it would happen also with `\footrue` after `\newif\iffoo`. Or simply even with `\relax\hline`.

Comment: indeed \def raises the same problem...

Comment: Yup, I will change the title

Comment: Also `\relax`, for instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\hline` uses a TeX primitive called `\noalign`, which only works if it is the very first (non-expandable) token in a tabular row. `\bool_set_true:N` performs an assignment, so it is not expandable and breaks `\hline` there.  You'd get the same error with `\def\x{} \hline` (assignment) or `\relax \hline` (non-expandable token `\relax`) or `a \hline` (non-expandable token `a`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  % \def\x{} \hline
  % \relax \hline
  % a \hline
  \hline
  test \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you really want the assignment there, you can put it *inside* `\noalign` (you can have multiple `\noalign`s in the same row).  Note that the assignment has to be global, otherwise it is reverted when the `\noalign` ends:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_show:N \g_tmpa_bool
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \noalign{ \bool_gset_true:N \g_tmpa_bool }
  \hline
  test \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\bool_show:N \g_tmpa_bool

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but I'd mention that you can put also the assignment in `\noalign` (though it should be made global).

Comment: @campa Note added

Comment: ...But why does \noalign needs to be first ? (sorry for this question getting "why ... thus why ... thus why ..." ^^')

Comment: @hl037_ Basically “because that's how Knuth designed TeX”, but a more rational reason could be because `\noalign` inserts stuff between two table rows, so it is the logical place to insert it (try `\begin{tabular}{c} \hline test \\ \noalign{a} test \\ \hline \end{tabular}` to see).