# Change multicolumn column spec with a star command

Tags: tables, multicolumn, xparse, optional-arguments

I am trying to make a macro that will wrap the column specification of a `\multicolumn` command with `@{}` if a `*` is passed to my macro. I can achieve the behaviour I want in the first definition below, but I am trying to figure out how to do it the "smarter" way, as attempted in the second definition, but it throws an error.  Why?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xparse}

%%% this gets me what I want
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\sCell}{s O{l} D(){1} m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF#1{%
        \multicolumn{#3}{#2}{#4}%
    }{%
        \multicolumn{#3}{@{}#2@{}}{#4}%
    }%
    }
    
%%% but I am trying to learn how to do it like this
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\sCell}{s O{l} D(){1} m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF#1{\def\colspec{#2}}{\def\colspec{@{}#2@{}}}
        \multicolumn{#3}{\colspec}{#4}%
}

\begin{document}

% this is the behaviour I want
\begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
\sCell{Hello}\\% 
\sCell*{Hello}\\% 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use `\def` there, more or less the same reason as here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590678/134574

Answer (score 3):

`\multicolumn` is built on top of a TeX primitive called `\omit`, and if `\omit` is used in a table cell it has to be the first non-expandable thing in the table cell ([besides `\omit`/`\hline`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590678/134574)).  `\def` is not expandable, so using it in your command before using the `\multicolumn` will not work because the `\def` will tell TeX that it doesn't have to look for `\omit` any longer, then later you give it an `\omit` and TeX complains.

A simpler example of the issue:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  % Any of these will cause the error.
  % \def\x{y}
  % \relax
  % a
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{error}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

That said, it seems you want to write your command without repeating the `\multicolumn`, so here are two options:

The first one, using an auxiliary.  Instead of defining `\colspec` with the proper argument, pass it to an auxiliary macro that will then use it in the `\multicolumn`.  This works because it uses, besides the `\IfBooleanTF` which is expandable, a macro which is by definition expandable:

```latex
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\sCell}{s O{l} D(){1} m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {\sCellaux{#2}}%
    {\sCellaux{@{}#2@{}}}%
      {#3}{#4}} % #3 and #4 outside the conditional because they are the same
\newcommand\sCellaux[3]{%
  \multicolumn{#2}{#1}{#3}}
```

The second option, using a few `expl3` auxiliaries, is to force the expansion of `\IfBooleanTF`, then shuffle things a bit to get the second argument in the right position.  This works because it uses some expandable primitives to trigger the expansion, and a macro to swap the arguments:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\sCell}{s O{l} D(){1} m }
  {
    \exp_args:Nf \use_ii_i:nn
      { \IfBooleanTF {#1} { {#2} } { {@{}#2@{}} } }
      { \multicolumn {#3} } {#4}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

---

Here's a compilable example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

%%% this gets me what I want
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\sCell}{s O{l} D(){1} m }
  {
    \exp_args:Nf \use_ii_i:nn
      { \IfBooleanTF {#1} { {#2} } { {@{}#2@{}} } }
      { \multicolumn {#3} } {#4}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%% this gets me what I want
% \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\sCell}{s O{l} D(){1} m }{%
%   \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
%     {\sCellaux{#2}}%
%     {\sCellaux{@{}#2@{}}}%
%       {#3}{#4}}
% \newcommand\sCellaux[3]{%
%   \multicolumn{#2}{#1}{#3}}

\begin{document}

% this is the behaviour I want
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\sCell{Hello}\\% 
\sCell*{Hello}\\% 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```